# Building a nested tree-like structure in Python using recursive or iterative approach

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, recursive-datastructures

I have been trying to build a nested tree-like structure for two days and decided to ask here for help. Suppose I have data like this:

```
rows = [
    {'Year': None, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 25}, # row 1 => SUM of (row 2 and row 14) = 15+25 = 40; this row represents, for example, all of the sales made so far (the ultimate total, if you will call it as such)
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 15}, # row 2 => SUM of sales from (row 3) = 15; this row represents, for example, the total of sales in 2013 from all regions, all countries, all manufacturers and all brands  
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 15}, #row 3 => SUM of sales from (row 4) = 15; this row represents, for example, the total of sales in LTM region for 2013  
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 15}, # row 4 => SUM of sales from (row 5+row 7+row 10+row12) = 1+5+4+5 = 15; this row represents, for example, the total of Sales in Colombia for 2013
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 1}, # row 5 => SUM of sales from (row 6) = 1
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B1', 'Sales': 1}, # row 6 => Nothing to sum here because this is the lowest hierarchy
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 5}, # row 7 => SUM of sales from (row 8 and row 9) = 2+3 = 5
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': 'B2', 'Sales': 2}, # row 8 => Nothing to sum here
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': 'B3', 'Sales': 3}, # row 9 => Nothing to sum here
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M3', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 4}, # row 10 => SUM of sales from (row 11) = 4
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M3', 'Brand': 'B4', 'Sales': 4}, # row 11 => Nothing to sum here
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M4', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 5}, # row 12 => SUM of sales from (row 13) = 5
    {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M4', 'Brand': 'B5', 'Sales': 5}, # row 13 => Nothing to sum here

    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 25}, # row 14 => SUM of sales from (row 15) = 25; represents total sales in 2014 from all regions, all countries, all manufacturers and all brands 
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 25}, # row 15 => SUM of sales from (row 16+row 18) = 15+10 = 25; represents total sales in 2014 from Chile and Colombia combined  
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 15}, # ** TRICKY: row 16 => SUM of sales from (row 17+row 20+row 21) =  0+5+10 = 15; total sales in 2014 for Chile 
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 15}, # row 17
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 10}, # row 18 => SUM of sales from (row 19) = 10; total sales in 2014 for Colombia
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Sales': 10}, # row 19
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B1', 'Sales': 5}, # row 20
    {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B6', 'Sales': 10}, # row 21
    # more data...
]
```

I am trying to write a function/method that has signature like this:

```
def build_tree(rows, hierarchy):
    pass # still can't get it right after ~2 days of trying
```

In the above signature, `hierarchy` is defined as: any combination of `['Year']+[any from the 'Region','Country','Manufacturer' and 'Brand']`. So for example, these are all legitimate hierarchy of the desired tree: `['Year','Region','Country']` or `['Year','Country','Manufacturer']` or `['Year','Country','Brand']`.

Suppose, `hierarchy=['Year','Country','Manufacturer']` and the input `rows` are the 21 visible ones that I've described above, the output of the function should look like this:

```
output = [
  {
    "name": 2013,
    "sales": 15, # total sales of 2013, which corresponds to 'Values: 15' of row #2 in input; alternatively, this "sales" can be calculated as the SUM(all "sales" of its IMMEDIATE children, which is the node with "name"="Colombia". We do NOT need to sum up the sales from children that are further down the hierarchy level such as that of 'children' from the 'Manufacturer' level)
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Colombia",
            "sales": 15, # total sales in Colombia in 2013 which corresponds to 'Sales' of row #4 in input (please note that our input 'hierarchy' skipped 'Region', so we are not showing the aggregate value of 'Region' (row #3) here); alternatively, this "sales" can be calculated as the SUM(all "sales" in its immediate children, "name"=M1, M2, M3 and M4)
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1", # total sales for Manufacturer 'M1' in 2013 which corresponds to 'Sales' of row #5 in input
                    "sales": 1,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M2",
                    "sales": 5, # total sales for Manufacturer 'M2' in 2013 which corresponds to 'Sales' of row #7 in input
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "sales": 4, # total sales for Manufacturer 'M3' in 2013 which corresponds to 'Sales' of row #10 in input
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M4",
                    "sales": 5, # total sales for Manufacturer 'M4' in 2013 which corresponds to 'Sales' of row #12 in input
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": 2014,
    "sales": 25, # sum of total sales in 2014; same as 'Sales' in row #14. Alternatively, we can just get the sum of its IMMEDIATE children, row#16 for 'Chile' and row#18 for Colombia, here
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Chile",
            "sales": 15, # sum of total sales in 2014 for Chile, which is row #16; alternatively, we can derive this value by adding up the sales of row #17 (that is, its immediate children listed ONE hierarchy below, which is 'Manufacturer')
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1",
                    "sales": 15, # corresponds to 'Sales' from row #17
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Colombia",
            "sales": 10, # corresponds to 'Sales' from row #18, which is equivalent to the sum of total sales from all manufacturers in 'Colombia' in 2014
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1",
                    "sales": 10, # corresponds to row #19; there's only one manufacturer reported for Colombia in 2014 in the input data
                    "children": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thanks very much in advance if you could share some tips/suggestions/answers!

Comment: My tip is that you need to edit the code you have tried to write, into the question, and describe why it isn’t working and what you have tried to get it working.

Comment: @barny The truth is I tried a few ways and gave up after getting lost. But I'll share what I have after trying at this problem again this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see the algorithm. I hope the code is easily readable.

This assignment `x0, *x = x` is Python3 syntax for detaching the first item of a list. In Python2: `x0 = x[0]; x = x[1:]`

There are two details you did not mention, see #comments

```
from collections import defaultdict

def build_tree(rows, hierarchy):
    if not hierarchy:
        return []
    h0, *hierarchy = hierarchy
    node = defaultdict(list)
    for row in rows:
        v0 = row[h0]
        if v0 is not None:  # filter out null values??
            node[v0].append(row)
    return [{
        'name': key,
        'value': None, # what is value??
        'children': build_tree(subrows, hierarchy)} for key, subrows in node.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did a quick run and your solution seems to work (need to test with more complex scenario). Sorry that I wasn't clear in my question: `value` is supposed to be the corresponding number (1,2,3,..,21) from the `'Value'` key in the row. And yes, filter out the `null` values. Today, I will 1) try to work on the solution myself again and if it works, I'll share here 2) try to understand your solution, test it with more scenarios (different hierarchy pairings), accept it if all checks out, and will ask you some follow-up questions if needed. Thank so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Feel free to ask about the code, but the 'value' is still not clear to me, because each part of the hierarchy represents multiple rows. This will be your homework.

Comment: hi again, I have decided to revisit this and started testing the suggested solution here. I updated my question above to explain better about what `'Value'` means. I also picked apart your code (put a debugger to understand what it is doing) to understand better and I think I get what you did there. :) But if my understanding is right, regardless of how I modify your suggested solution, we would not be able to retrieve/set the corresponding `'value'` for each node. Could you please take a second look at my updated question and let me know your thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: And, I'll try again to implement my own solution tomorrow and will share if I can crack it. :)

Comment: @user1330974 Your recent edit changed only the input data. You have some value assigne every leaf on the input list and want to have a value for every node in the output tree. Please explain how it is computed. If value means sales, is the tree node value some kind of sum?

Comment: I'm sorry about the poor choice of the `'key'` name. I've changed `'Value'` to `'Sales'` to make things, hopefully, easier to understand. I also added more comments alongside the output. Please let me know if it now makes sense. I'll be working on this problem today. For what is worth, this input data is derived directly from the output of the earlier question I've posted on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518148/1330974
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Regarding the linked SO question: IMHO this is now a so called XY problem. The hierarchy should be the input for building the SQL query. It makes little sense to regroup records in Python when the database should give you the answer structured as you want.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. I have to build the data into tree like structure because the visualization library (ECharts) requires the data to be in that format... I'll keep trying and will update here once/if I crack it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
import itertools
rows = [{'Year': None, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 1}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 2}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 3}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 4}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 5}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B1', 'Value': 6}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 7}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': 'B2', 'Value': 8}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M2', 'Brand': 'B3', 'Value': 9}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M3', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 10}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M3', 'Brand': 'B4', 'Value': 11}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M4', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 12}, {'Year': 2013, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M4', 'Brand': 'B5', 'Value': 13}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': None, 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 14}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': None, 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 15}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 16}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 17}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': None, 'Value': 18}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Colombia', 'Manufacturer': None, 'Brand': None, 'Value': 19}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B1', 'Value': 20}, {'Year': 2014, 'Region': 'LTM', 'Country': 'Chile', 'Manufacturer': 'M1', 'Brand': 'B6', 'Value': 21}]
def __lt__(_rows, key, current):
  new_rows = list(filter(None, [i[current] for i in _rows]))
  return {'int':0, 'str':''}.get(type(new_rows[0]).__name__) if key is None else key

def group_data(d, hierarchy=['Year','Country','Manufacturer']):
  start, *_h = hierarchy
  first = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:__lt__(rows, x[start], start)), key=lambda x:__lt__(rows, x[start], start))]
  return [{'name':a, 'value':min(b, key=lambda x:x['Value'])['Value'], 'children':[] if not _h else group_data(b, _h)} for a, b in first if a]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(group_data(rows), indent = 4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": 2013,
    "value": 2,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Colombia",
            "value": 4,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1",
                    "value": 5,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M2",
                    "value": 7,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M3",
                    "value": 10,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "M4",
                    "value": 12,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": 2014,
    "value": 14,
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Chile",
            "value": 16,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1",
                    "value": 17,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Colombia",
            "value": 18,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "M1",
                    "value": 18,
                    "children": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: your solution is really advanced and neat! I finally got around to test it and it's really close. But because of my mistake in representing and explaining the raw data (`rows`) poorly, the suggested solution does not get the `"value"` right... I have updated the question with the explanation of what `Value` in each row means. I tried to tweak your solution to get it to work, but since I cannot fully comprehend this part `'value':min(b, key=lambda x:x['Value'])['Value']`, it's proving a bit challenging. Could you pls take a second look? Thank you.